# Dolphin{anty} request localhost error downloadDatadirError

Tags: dolphin-browser

Today i get problem in dolphin request return this message

{"success":false,"message":"downloadDatadirError"}

I don't now where is the problem i try to change url but not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is a server-sided issue, because I have the same problem as you, but a few hours before everything was alright, so I guess we can only wait for devs to resolve the issue

Comment: I asked technical support about the issue, they told the problem is only on free subscription plan, and they will fix it on this week

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).